# How to delete Digital Ocean Space with lots files

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a space in Digital Oceans with about 1 million files adding up to 60GB. I want to delete the space, but when I do that they tell that I can't delete it before manually removing the files since I have so many.

Their instructions are:

> When using the control panel, there is currently a limitation on how many files a Space can contain when being destroyed. To successfully delete this Space:
>
> 1. Use the file manager (or CLI tool) to manually delete all of the files in the Space.
> 2. Destroy the Space using the CLI tool.

I've tried deleting files in their file manager, but those operations failed.

What is the best way to delete these files? I don't see a particular CLI tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can use s3cmd like this:

```sh
$ s3cmd del -r -v s3://yourbucket/folder
```

Note `-r` option for recursive operation

Answer (score 0):

fastest way I can think of would be to mount your space on a droplet (any droplet) in a new directory (let's say you mount it on `/home/your_user/dead_space_walking`) with `s3-fuse` or similar tools, then delete your files using simple command-line resources like `rm -rf /home/your_user/dead_space_walking`

It may take a long while to destroy a million files, but once it's done, just go back to DO's admin panel and destroy the Space.

Comment: I've been running this command for 5 days now and it's deleted 200k files, so I have about another 20 days to go. I wonder if there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: Object-storage operations are in fact much slower than regular file operations (that's an object storage reality, sadly). I didn't expect it to take THAT much time though. Have you tried reaching out to DO support?

Comment: Yeah. I did reach out to DO support. They suggested doing the same thing you did. On my own, I looked into how AWS S3 handles this problem. S3 suggests changing the retention policy to 1 day and letting things get auto-deleted. It looks like that might be possible on DO Spaces, but that retention policy can only be changed via API.